# Error exporting Python Coverage to XML "no such table: tracer"

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

After run coverage with unittest i got this error:

Command:
`coverage xml -i -o coverage.xml`

Give me this error:

```
Couldn't use data file 'project/coverage.xml': no such table: tracer
```

```
Python: 3.6.9
Coverage: 6.2
```

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: @ChuckConway not yet...

Comment: I was able to get around it by dropping to coverage version 4.5.4.